# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'valueFromAPICall() ')

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am stuck with an error while executing the unit tests using Jasmine.

**Here is my `karma.config.js`:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath:'./',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      'app/testSpeed.js',
      'app/*.spec.js'
    ],

    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-spec-reporter',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-jasmine',
    ],

    reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'],   

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    singleRun: true

  });
};
```

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
var getValue=function(){
    return 'valueFromAPICall()';
};
```

**Unit Test:**

```
describe('valueFromAPICall', function() {
    it('expecting an integer value', function() {
        expect(getValue()).toBe(0)); //0 is the value returned by 'valueFromAPICall'
    })
});
```

**`package.json`:**

```
    "karma": "^0.12.14",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.12",
```

The trouble is I am getting this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'valueFromAPICall()')

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to return a string here?    `var getValue=function(){
      return 'valueFromAPICall()';
    };`

Comment: `getValue` returns the string "valueFromAPICall()" -- you expect this to be 0...?

Comment: Nathan and pdenes: thank you very much for reply; that's my bad i would've mentioned with out quotes.., any how i am expecting an integer value, could be 0 or 1 or 2...

Comment: Can you please show the full stack trace for the error? Or maybe more code from where the error is coming from? (You can also edit the post to remove the quotes.)